# kubernetes Clusterip+port is not reachable in some cases

Tags: docker, kubernetes

l tried to set up a dvwa environment in k8s, l found it not work as usual when l exposed the dvwa pods's port.

l tried exposing a nginx sample to make sure my k8s env is working. And yes nginx works well in my local machine

Here is some information

```
# dvwa.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: dvwa
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    app: dvwa
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dvwa
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dvwa
          image: citizenstig/dvwa:latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3306


# dvwa_service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dvwa
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: dvwa
  type: NodePort


$ kubectl get svc -o wide
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          
AGE     SELECTOR
dvwa              NodePort    10.98.238.130   <none>        
3306:32393/TCP   7m15s   app=dvwa
kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          
35h     <none>
nginx             NodePort    10.97.143.32    <none>        
80:31961/TCP     5m51s   app=nginx
```

When l ssh into one of my k8s machine and typed `curl 10.97.143.32:80`, it returns the nginx page, but `curl 10.98.238.130:3306` not works, the docker image is `citizenstig/dvwa` which expose 80 and 3306, l also tried using 80 port in dvwa_service.yaml but still not work.

Can anyone help me??? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

targetPort is missing in your service definition

Try below service definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dvwa
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: dvwa
  type: NodePort
```

can you get into the dvwa pod and run localhost:3306
do you get any response?

Comment: Thanks for answering! l tried the above in my minikube env it works but also without targetPort. When l turned to my three nodes env(l use kubeadm-dind-cluster) described in my question, only the nginx works which really confused me...

Comment: refer the output from kubectl get svc. the port number is empty. targetPort is required to ensure that service binds to that port on the pods

Comment: what do you mean by the port number is empty? The port number do exists (but in a new line).. actually my nginx pod is also missing targetPort but it works..

Comment: i see them now.